# Simple Search Function in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm using Q lookup for simple search Functionality. Here's the code taken from view,

```
    if query:
    object_list = Post.objects.filter(
        Q(title__icontains=query) |
        Q(content__icontains=query)
        ).distinct()
```

But I have another model "Question", I wants to filter out questions in the search as well along-with Post.

How can I use Q lookup for 2 separate models i.e. 'Post' & 'Question' together in one variable i.e "object_list".

Please help me with this code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the `Q` object, reuse it for each model query and then chain the querysets:

```
from itertools import chain

q_obj = Q(title__icontains=query) | Q(content__icontains=query)
object_list = chain(Post.objects.filter(q_obj).distinct(), 
                    Question.objects.filter(q_obj).distinct())
```

This allows you to iterate on `object_list` once. To allow for multiple iterations, you can turn the iterator returned by `chain` into a list:

```
object_list = list(chain(Post.objects.filter(q_obj).distinct(), 
                         Question.objects.filter(q_obj).distinct()))
```

Comment: WOW, Working Perfectly Fine. Thank you very much Sir :)